# How to change the day format in resource view using library React FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm using React FullCalendar with the resource view, specifically the `resourceTimelineWeek` view.

Currently, the day format in the header is displayed in the default format. I want to customize it to a different format (e.g., "Sunday", "Monday").

Fullcalendar resource time line view with custom 7 days

[image]

```
views={{
    timeLineWeek: {
       type: "resourceTimelineWeek",
       slotDuration: { days: 1 },
    },
}}
```

Comment: This is already documented: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat

Comment: titleFormat: { year: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'long' } https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

Comment: @Chalas that's for the title, not the individual slot headings. Read the question again.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve the problem, but apparently I need to reinstall fullcalendar and tslib because fullcalendar requires tslib. I ran into many problems and I was frustrated with it and did not understand why It wasn't working and I am following the documentation.